# Performance of In Operator with OR conditional SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have common clause in Most of the Procedures like

```
Select * from TABLE A  + Joins  where <Conditions>

And 
(
     -- All Broker
       ('True' = (Select AllBrokers from SiteUser where ID = @SiteUserID)) 
  OR 
       ( 
         A.BrokerID in 
                     (
                       Select BrokerID from SiteUserBroker where SiteUserID 
                      = @SiteUserID)
       )
)
```

So basically if the user has access to all brokers the whole filter should not be applied else if should get the list of Broker

I am bit worries about the performance as this is used in lot of procedures and data has started reaching over 100,000 records and will grow soon, so can this be better written?

ANY Ideas are highly appreciated

Comment: that does not look like valid TSQL to me.

Answer (score 1):

One of the techniques is to use built dynamic T-SQL statement and then execute it. Since, this is done in stored procedure you are OK and the idea is simple.

```
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = 'base query';

IF 'Getting All Brokers is not allowed '
BEGIN;
    SET @DynamicTSQLStatement = @DynamicTSQLStatement + 'aditional where clause'
END;

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```

Or instead of using dynamic T-SQL statement you can have two separate queries - one for users seeing all the data and one for users seeing part of the data. This can lead to code duplication.

Another way, is to turn this `OR` statement in `INNER JOIN`. You should test the performance in order to be sure you are getting something from it. The idea is to create a temporary table (it can have primary key or indexes if needed) and store all visible broker ids there - if the users sees all, then `Select BrokerID from SiteUserBroker` and if the users sees a few - `Select BrokerID from SiteUserBroker where SiteUserID = @SiteUserID`. In the second way, you are going to simplify the whole statement, but be sure to test if performance is improved.

```
CREATE TABLE #SiteUserBroker
(
    [BrokerID] INT PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO #SiteUserBroker ([BrokerID])
SELECT BrokerID
FROM SiteUserBroker
where SiteUserID = @SiteUserID
    OR ('True' = (Select AllBrokers from SiteUser where ID = @SiteUserID)); 



Select * 
from TABLE A
INNER JOIN #SiteUserBroker B
    ON A.BrokerID = B.[BrokerID]
-- other joins
where <Conditions>
```

As we are using `INNER JOIN` you can add it at the begging. If there are `LEFT JOINs` after it, it will affect the performance in positive way.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, couple of suggestion i thought as well but i like to avoid dynamic sql and also code duplication. your third suggestion looks promising but not able to figure out the way to implement it.

Comment: @Moons Check the example and let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: example seems great, but out of CTE, Table variable and temporary table what you will prefer assuming this is going to be called few thousands time a day and any impact

Comment: @Moons, I generally prefer using temporary tables when I am expecting to have hundreds of rows. They perform better then the others in terms of performance when large result sets are handled (generally). You are not allowed to use #temporary table in functions for example, so sometimes one have no choice. Check this great answer about table variables and temporary tables  - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386/6171

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @gotqn answer, you can add `EXISTS` instead of `IN` (Note - This is not complete answer) -

```
AND EXISTS (
     Select 1/0 from SiteUserBroker X
     where A.BrokerID = X.BrokerID  AND
     X.SiteUserID = @SiteUserID
)
```

I found that `Exists` performs better than `In` in some cases. Please verify your case.

Comment: So you recommend code that produces a [divide by zero] error?

Comment: I recommend code which is self explainable....In above code, EXISTS will check existence of record so 1/0 will never be executed.